# Cannot render raw html

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to return as ajax response a raw html, this is the function that return the response:

```
res.render('partial/messages', {
        successMsg: 'An email has been sent to you.' +
            '<a href="' + req.headers.host + '/user/resendToken?email=' + user.email + '">Send Again.</a>',
        layout: false
    }, function (err, list) { 
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.status(200).send({ msg: list }); 
    });
```

the partial view `message` contains the following:

```
<% if(successMsg != ''){ %>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <%= successMsg %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<% } %>
```

the ajax response is:

```
" 
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    An email has been sent to you.`&lt;a href=&#34;127.0.0.1:3000/user/resendToken?email=foo@outlook.it&#34;&gt;Send Again.&lt;/a&gt;`
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
  "
```

why the `<a href` tag is render `&alt;` ?

How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&alt;` is the HTML entity corresponding to `<`. This is used to prevent code injection.

EJS is doing the transformation when you include a string using the `<%= something %>` syntax.

To prevent it, use the `<%- something %>` syntax.

Keep in mind that not escaping those characters may expose your service to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Because `<%= ... %>` escapes the HTML. If you are sure you can trust the `user.email` and other user generated data, you can use the `<%- successMsg %>` instead, which won't escape the HTML.

You can read more about tags in the [Docs section of EJS here](https://ejs.co/#docs).